# Can retrieve product category ID but category name is always null

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, category-products

I need to be able to get the Category name and ID from a product and I am able to retrieve the ID doing the following:

```
$categoryID = $product->getCategoryCollection()->getFirstItem()->getId();
```

However If I try to get the name, It always returns null.

```
$categoryName = $product->getCategoryCollection()->getFirstItem()->getName();
```

How do I get the name?

I have tried loading the Category by ID but that seems to be returning null as well, I have checked in the admin screen the correct ID for the category is returned.

Answer (score 6):

try it like this:

```
$product->getCategoryCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->getFirstItem()
    ->getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this should work:

```
$categoryID = $product->getCategoryCollection()->getFirstItem()->getId();
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryID);
$categoryName = $category->getName();
```

If it doesn't (as you write), I can't imagine why. However, have you tried this?

```
$categoryName = $product->getCategoryCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name')->getFirstItem()->getName();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but still returns null. Seems weird I can get the ID but not the name

Comment: If the category exists, at least the `load()`-method should return something. And `$product->getCategoryCollection()->count()` is `> 0`? Can you add the output of `$product->getCategoryCollection()->addAttributeToSelect()->getFirstItem()->debug()` to your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @param $product_id
 * @return array
 */
public function mc_getCategoryIds($product_id)
{
//       +++ get product the category id
    $registry = $this->mc_C['product'];
    $getObj = $this->mc_get_obj($registry);
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $getObj
     * \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    $product = $getObj->load($product_id);

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */

    return $product->getCategoryIds();
}

/**
 * @param $product_id
 * @return mixed
 */
public function mc_getCategoryName($product_id)
{
    $cats = $this->mc_getCategoryIds($product_id);
    if(count($cats) ){
        $firstCategoryId = $cats[(count($cats)-1)];
        $registry = $this->mc_C['category'];
        $getObj = $this->mc_get_obj($registry);

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $getObj
         */
        $_category = $getObj->create();
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $_category
         */
        $data = $_category->load($firstCategoryId);
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $data
         */
        return $data->getName();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

https://www.cnblogs.com/q1104460935/p/11237280.html